# Is there any in GWT to get notification about which fragment is going to be downloaded

Tags: javascript, gwt

Our GWT application has various fragments and each of them are very big in size(1+ MB). What we would like to do is to show a progress bar when GWT is downloading the fragment. We are using GWTP based code splitting.

I could not find anything related to fragment loading event in GWT source code. Does anyone have any idea about how Javascript on page can be notified about which fragment is going to be downloaded next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not any direct way, but you can workaround that basically in two ways

1.- Extending the `CrossSiteIframeLinker` and overriding the method `getJsInstallScript()` so as you can return a customised javascript content which could alert somehow to the user about the permutation being loaded or simply show a spinner. Note that your script should contain a code similar to `installScriptEarlyDownload.js` or `installScriptDirect.js`

```
// Your linker class
public class MyXSILinker extends CrossSiteIframeLinker {
  @Override
  protected String getJsInstallScript(LinkerContext context) {
    return "/your_namespace/your_script.js";
  }
}

// your "/your_namespace/your_script.js" script
function installScript(filename) {
}

// your module file
<define-linker name="mylinker" class="...MyXSILinker" />
<add-linker name="mylinker" />
```

2.- Using the `window.__gwtStatsEvent` function. You can define a function in your `index.html` to start a loading spinner when the script loading the app is going to be added to your document, then use your gwt code to remove that.

```
// In your index.html
<head>
<script>
window.__gwtStatsEvent = function(r) {
  if (r.type == 'scriptTagAdded') {
    d = document.createElement('div')
    d.id = 'loading'
    d.innerHTML = 'Loading...'
    document.body.appendChild(d);
  }
}
</head>
</script>

// In your EntryPoint class
Document.get().getElementById("loading").removeFromParent();
```

To show an accurate progress-bar is quite difficult because `<script>` tag does not support progress events. So the best approach should be a linker loading the permutation using ajax, so as you can use html5 progress events in the `xhr` object.

I would use the #2 approach showing a nice spinner animated with css.

Comment: 2nd solution does not seem to work. function is called many times but type never matches with scriptTagAdded.

Comment: Which linker are you using? Because phases depends on it. Try sending to console log each r.type reveived to figure out what matches your needs.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot. I used __gwtStatsEvent to identify loading start and size of the initial download to calculate the percentage.